# R Programing beginner

Tags: r, statistics

Hi I am new to Data analytics.I am planning to learn R by doing some real time projects. How should I stream line (set goals) my time in learning R and also I have not learnt statistics till data. I am planning to learn both side by side. I am mid level data warehouse engineer who has experience in DBMS Data-Integration. I am planning to learn R so that I can bring out useful analysis from the Integrated data.

If I be specific, I am beginning in R, so what are the basic statistical concepts I should know and implement it in R. If I want to be an expert or above average person in R how should I plan strategically to become one. Say if I can spend 2 hrs a day for 1 year what level I should reach. FYI am working for a SaaS company. What are the way s in which I can utilize R knowledge in a SaaS environment

Comment: I think questions that are purely about career and off site learning resources for a tool are off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second saq7 and Gopinath, the R courses on Coursera are excellent. I really rate the Johns Hopkins ones: https://www.coursera.org/specialization/jhudatascience/1/courses. You should also keep an eye on the [software carpentry](http://software-carpentry.org/) site for courses they run in your area. If you can't wait, all the software carpentry [learning material is online](http://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-inflammation/) so you can follow it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I would start off with [All Of Statistics by Larry Wasserman](http://www.amazon.ca/All-Statistics-Concise-Statistical-Inference/dp/0387402721). This quickly gets you upto speed with statistics assuming you have some mathematical background. I think all it needs is introductory calculus and linear algebra.

R is pretty straightforward to pick up and there are a number of resources you can use. The [R Programming](https://www.coursera.org/course/rprog) course on coursera is an excellent short course to get you familiarized with R. Besides that there are a number of books and tutorials on the subject.

I would recommend you start working through All of Statistics and start playing around in R along with that book.

If you are at a SaaS company, there are a number of data sciency roles and responsibilities that should be available. Most SaaS companies will have analytical tools to provide basic insight. Once you start learning statistics and data science, you will be able to identify the gaps in the pre baked tools and ways to improve them. I would also read [The Field Guide to Data Science](http://www.boozallen.com/insights/2013/11/data-science-field-guide), it's a short book that will give you a high level idea of data science and its utility.

Answer (score 1):

The MOOCs like UDACITY, COURSERA, UDEMY and EDX  are a great place to learn high quality R programming courses free. You can also search on the MOOCTIVITY siter which is a MOOC aggregator.

I have personally found great courses on R programming at  UDACITY, COURSERA and UDEMY and also EDX.

Good Luck !!

Gopinath SUbbegowda